# Is there a way to retrieve the shape of a styled object from a database?

Tags: sld

I am working with geoserver on an oracle database.

I am trying to generalize my SLDs and make them more dynamic. The idea is to store all styling information in the database and let the SLD retrieve it dynamically.
I found out that this works well for fill, stroke and some other atrributes like opacity, size and rotation. As can be seen below where SLD_FILL and SLD_SIZE are the columns where the actual fill and size styling data is stored.

```
<PointSymbolizer>
<Graphic>
     <Mark>
     <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
         <Fill>
         <CssParameter name="fill">
         <ogc:PropertyName>SLD_FILL</ogc:PropertyName>
         </CssParameter>
         </Fill>
     </Mark>
     <Size>
     <ogc:PropertyName>SLD_SIZE</ogc:PropertyName>
     </Size>
</Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

I have tried this also with the shape of a marker where the column SLD-SHAPE stores the text circle:

```
<PointSymbolizer>
  <Graphic>
     <Mark>
     <WellKnownName>
     <ogc:PropertyName>SLD_SHAPE</ogc:PropertyName>
     </WellKnownName>
         <Fill>
         <CssParameter name="fill">
         <ogc:PropertyName>SLD_FILL</ogc:PropertyName>
         </CssParameter>
         </Fill>
     </Mark>
     <Size>
     <ogc:PropertyName>SLD_SIZE</ogc:PropertyName>
     </Size>
  </Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

This does not work. Does anyone know if this is possible?